# Ionic Undefined despues de hacer get

Tags: angular, angular5, ionic-framework

Hola tengo problemas con IONIC, cada vez que imprimo console.log(this.items) imprime undefined, sin embargo console.log(data) imprime sin problemas.

- Ionic App Scripts: 3.2.0
- Angular Core: 5.2.11
- Angular Compiler CLI: 5.2.11
- Node: 8.11.2

Nota: Quiero recorrer esa variable en el mismo controlador, no en la vista.
Agradeceria mucho su ayuda, saludos.

```
export class AccederPage {
  items:any;
  usuario:String;
  clave:String;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,public alertCtrl: AlertController, public http: HttpClient) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {  
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad AccederPage');
  }
  login(){    
    this.http.get("https://xxx.com/yyy/empleados").subscribe(
      (data=>{
        this.items=data; 
        console.log(data);
      }),
      (
        error=>{
          console.log(error);
        }
      )
    );
   console.log(this.items);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es normal que así suceda.

En la función login lo que haces es primero hacer una petición a una URL:

`this.http.get("https://xxx.com/yyy/empleados")`

Y le añades un subcriptor al resultado de esa llamada. Pero esa llamada se ejecuta asíncronamente, es decir, se realiza la petición al servidor y en vez de esperar la respuesta sin hacer nada se continua ejecutando el código JavaScript.

Por tanto, lo siguiente que se ejecuta es:

`console.log(this.items);`

Que devuelve undefined porque no hay items aún.

Un poco después llegará la respuesta del servidor y se e exitosa se ejecutará la parte de la subscripción correspondiente:

```
(data=>{
        this.items=data; 
        console.log(data);
      }
```

Ahí fijas el valor de `this.items` y por tanto si escribieses `console.log(this.items)` debería mostrarte el valor recibido sin problema.

Lo que tienes que hacer es *recorrer* esa variable dentro del código de que recibe el dato, que sería en el `subscribe`. Aunque probablemente si quieres transformarlo lo que deberías hacer es usar operadores de RxJS. Por ejemplo, aquí los comentan: https://pablomagaz.com/blog/como-funcionan-operadores-rxjs

Comment: Muchas gracias, el inconveniente era la petición asyncrona, me has ayudado bastante. :)